# After full-screen video, Chrome autoscroll to page top

Tags: google-chrome

Is it a normal behaviour of Chrome that, after putting a video in full-screen mode, and then exiting, it scrolls to the top of the page?

Thanks

Comment: Catch the scroll position and restore when exiting from full screen, use fullscreen event to capture.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a litte late, but I had the same problem right now. I had the CSS style `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `body` element to hide an ugly horizonal scroll bar. Removing it fixed the problem and Chrome stopped jumping to the top on enter/leave fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the main method and it fixed the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webview.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce the result again.

Answer (score 0):

remove `display:none;` from this class

```
:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor>:not(:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor):not(:-webkit-full-screen)
```